# If we replace dye in a Couette cell by little plastic balls, will rotating the cell show reversible behavior of the colloid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reversibility

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcBpDVzBPMk) great video, presented by R.I. Taylor, you can see that a dye introduced into a Couette cell shows reversible behavior if the walls of the two cylinders are turned a few times after which they are turned back again.

Now suppose we replace the dye with small, plastic balls (which thus form a colloidal, i.e. if they are not too far apart)) that are arranged in a certain shape.

Will, after turning the two walls of the cells to and fro, the form of the initial shape of the collections of these little balls emerge again, just like the dye? Or will a different shape emerge? Or, if the last is the case, will after a certain number times turning the walls to and fro, a non-changing shape of the balls see the light?

Comment: In my judgment, a dilute colloidal suspension will exhibit the same "reversible" characteristic as the dye solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you keep the flow in a low Reynolds number domain, then yes, you will be able to demonstrate reversible flow with small plastic balls.

Having given this demonstration a number of times, however, I think you may lose some of the impact. With a liquid dot, when it gets smeared out it entirely loses its apparent integrity, making its coalescence a real Wow! moment. While the balls may spread out, they begin and end as a collection of balls and I fear this would dilute the effect (pun absolutely intended)

Comment: The balls can be colored as well. However I do agree that even with colored plastic balls it brings less visual impact.

Comment: It's less about the color and more about the impact of the change of state between closely collected and spread out.